# What was the inspiration for the Framework in Agents of Shield?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

As far as I can tell, the Framework (the computer simulation first appearing in S4E11) did not appear in the comics.

Have there been any official comments or explanations as to the creative origin or intention of the Framework by the production staff or crew of the television series?

Comment: Could whoever downvoted me please explain what they didn't like about my post so that I can improve it, since I'm new around here and am still learning the ropes of how this community works and the nuances of what questions are allowed?

Comment: I took a shot at editing the question to hopefully improve it. I'm not familiar w/ either the comics or the show, so that puts me at a disadvantage there, but I agree, I didn't see anything inherently bad about your question (assuming my edit matches your intentions). Good luck and welcome!

Answer (score 2):

While there has been no official statement from the creators, the Framework storyline appears to be largely based upon the currently ongoing [Secret Empire](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Secret_Empire_(Event)) comics event. Even the timing of the comic event and the episodes match up.

In this event, Captain America is revealed to have been a secret Agent of HYDRA, and all of the repercussions from that - including a future where HYDRA wins the war and takes over.

<sub>-[More info about Secret Empire](http://www.polygon.com/comics/2017/4/18/15327018/secret-empire-explained)</sub>